# Don't understand why this std::cout is printing this

Tags: c++, while-loop, cout, cin

I got is c++ code below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char ch;
int ct1, ct2;
ct1 = ct2 = 0;
while ((ch = cin.get()) != '$')
{
    cout << ch;
    ct1++;
    if (ch = '$')
        ct2++;
    cout << ch;
}
cout << "ct1 = " << ct1 << ", ct2 = " << ct2 << "\n";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Now you can tell what gonna happen if input.

```
  hi$<ENTER>
```

and the the output should be this right.

```
hi ct1 = 2, ct2 = 0
```

But the real output is this.

```
h$i$ct1 = 2, ct2 = 2.
```

why is it outputting that i don't understand and how should i fix it.

and i'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 preview for windows desktop.

Comment: You have `if (ch = '$')`. That's an assignment, not a comparison, so it counts as `true` in every iteration of the loop. You want `if (ch == '$')` instead.

Comment: This question is about a typo (or something similar). Voting to put on hold.

Comment: `ch` should have type `int` (or you should write `while ( cin.get() && ch != '$' )`; as written, you'll go into an endless loop if you reach end of file.

Comment: Also, if you really mean `if ( ch == '$' )` in the loop, the condition will always be false (since you don't enter the loop if `ch == '$').

Comment: I just realized my comment is a bit misleading. The assignment of course does not necessarily evaluate to `true`. It evaluates to whatever is assigned, which is `$`, and that evaluates to `true` because it is not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **if** statement, you actually assigned $ to `ch` : `if(ch = '$')`. This should be :

```c
if(ch == '$')
```

---

Also, your real output will be like this : `hhiict1 = 2, ct2 = 0`, since you wrote `cout << ch;` two times in your while statement.

Answer (score 2):

first, there is a problem in this code, if(ch = '$'),
second, I think the real output is "hhct1 = 1,ct2 = 0", because when the char is equal to '$', can get into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator = instead of == in if condition.
I would recommend.

```
if('$' == ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((ch = cin.get()) != '$')
{
    cout << ch;
    ct1++;
    if (ch = '$') // << here is the heck
          ^^^     // did you mean == ?
        ct2++;
    cout << ch;
}
```